# UITableView bounds when scrolls up?

Tags: uitableview, frame, bounds

My UIViewController contains only UITableView,here my tableview frame is for example (0,0, 320, 480) this is always same because "frame is relative to superview". Here i want to know is when scrolls the UITableView 100px up at this point of time what is my UITableView bounds?